# The wolf among us ending is ambiguous to me

Tags: the-wolf-among-us

In the last scene, the little mermaid(Nerissa) says the sentence which Faith said at the beginning of the game:

> I'll see you around, Wolf

After that Bigby seems to understand sth and, the player can choose to go after Nerissa or to get back inside.

What does Bigby find out?